# C++ While loop not iterating to next line in text file

Tags: c++, while-loop

I seem to be having a huge issue with my loops.
**What the program does**: The program reads a text file and gives each line of the text file in a string format. The data I want in the string are separated by tabs, so I am parsing through, finding the tabs and adding up all the characters until I hit the first tab. I then add the characters up until the tab and add it to an array so I can later evaluate the data.

> My Inner while Loop is parsing my first line correctly but is not iterating to the next line in the text file.

```
//Creates a temporary array
string current_line; //declare var line
string temp_string = "";
//When getline hits 'n' we are adding that to the string current_line
cout<<"Entering the Loop \n"<<endl;

// Gets the first line in the Text file and continutes to get each  new line
// until we hit the end of file
while(getline(infile,current_line,'\n').good()){

    //cout << "CURRENT SIZE " << current_line.size() << endl;

    /* iterates through each character as long as the size of the current
    line is greater than the counter i
    */
    while(i < current_line.size()){

        // If the Current character in the line is NOT a tab we add the
        // character to string temp_storage
        if(current_line[i] != '\t'){
            temp_storage +=current_line[i];
            }

        /*If the Current Character in the line is a tab then we store
        string temp_storage into another variable. Temp is cleared so we
        can get the next word in the string
        */
        else if (current_line[i] =='\t'){
             Storage = temp_storage;
            cout << "Current val:  "<< Storage <<endl;
            // Clears the temporary storage
            temp_storage = "";
            cout << "Clearing the temp_storage..."<< temp_storage<<endl;
            }
        //out << i << endl;
        i++; // iterates the loop
    }
    cout<<"loop finished"<<endl;
}
```

//Here is the output of running the program

Thanks for reading!

[image]

Comment: you never reset i for next line

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky I totally missed that thanks so much!

Comment: @MichaelBurr Will do thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not into 'modern' stuff like stream iterators, I would use the 'old' constructs as they were intended. Try a `for` loop. A while statement can do anything, but if you're just iterating with counter, a `for` loop is simply much better suited.

If you had done that, you could have hardly gone wrong:

`for ( int i=0; i<current_line.size(); i++ )`

In your code, the `i` can even have any value entering this code section.

Comment: Just a suggestion..., I would rephrase the answer to be friendlier

Comment: @purpletentacle OK I see what you mean. Hopefully it's better now.